# Loop generated buttons with 1 JQuery function, Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

### Generated table using php

I have loop generated button but everytime i press a button, JQuery function is not working, I must admit that I am not yet good at jQuery or AJAX. I want to increase the number of quantity without refreshing the page.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['placed_order'])){
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['placed_order'] as $keys => $values){
    ?>  
    <!-------------------------------------- QUANTITY CONTROL ----------------------------------------->
    <tr>
        <td id="table_content"><?php echo $values['item_name'];?></td>

        <td id="table_action">
            <span id="qty_display_<?php echo $values['item_name']; ?>"><?php echo $values['item_quantity'];?></span>

            <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $values['item_name'];?>" value="<?php echo $values['item_name'];?>">

            <button id="btn_<?php echo $values['item_name'];?>" class="text-success" onclick="inc_qty($('#<?php echo $values['item_name'];?>').val());" value="<?php echo $values['item_name'];?>">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" style="margin-left: 10%;"></span>
            </button>

            <a href="" class="text-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
        </td>

        <td id="table_content"><?php echo $values['price'];?></td>

        <td id="table_content"><?php echo number_format($values['item_quantity'] * $values['price'],2); ?></td>

        <td id="table_action">
            <a href="prototype.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values['item_id'];?>"><span class="text-danger">Remove</span></a>
            |
            <a href="prototype.php?action=update&id=<?php echo $values['item_id'];?>"><span class="text-info">Update</span></a>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php
    $total = $total + ($values['item_quantity'] * $values['price']);
}
?>
```

And this is my script

```
<script>
        function inc_qty(product_name){

            var qty_val = parseInt($('#qty_display_'+product_name).text());
            qty_val = qty_val + 1;
            $('#qty_display_'+product_name).text(qty_val);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: change `onclick="inc_qty($('#<?php echo $values['item_name'];?>').val());"` to just `onclick="inc_qty('<?php echo $values['item_name'];?>');"`. Your function `function inc_qty(product_name)`, just needs the `item_name`.

Comment: @Sean I'll give it a shot.